# add predefine textarea in CKEDITOR4

Tags: textarea, ckeditor4.x

im using IPS, and i wish to add predefine autofill textarea in the ckeditor text field.

so when a page with ckeditor feild is loading, it will have spesific words in it.

and is the area is requaird and the user do not fill it, the system will act as the user have filed it and will save the form with the autofill of the textarea.

i have tryd to locate the textarea file location without success.
i just need the textarea file location so i can add the code i need.

for exsample:

`<textarea>
my predefine autofill text
</textarea>`

thank you.

Answer (score -1):

i have figurd it out.

the way to add autofill texterea in all ckeditor4 location is here:

in the html editor of the IPS
core->global->forms->editorRaw

at this line of code:

```
<textarea name="{$name}" data-role='contentEditor' class="ipsHide" tabindex='1'>{$value|doubleencode} add data here</textarea>
```

[image: location of the text in the code]

hope it will help someone.